# Django CMS error when displaying advanced settings for page

Tags: django-cms

This is the error I get when trying to change the advanced settings of a page while in admin mode:

```
TypeError at /admin/cms/page/5/advanced-settings/
__str__ returned non-string (type __proxy__)

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/cms/page/5/advanced-settings/?language=en&cms_path=/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['djangocms_admin_style',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'cms',
 'menus',
 'sekizai',
 'treebeard',
 'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
 'filer',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'djangocms_column',
 'djangocms_file',
 'djangocms_link',
 'djangocms_picture',
 'djangocms_style',
 'djangocms_snippet',
 'djangocms_googlemap',
 'djangocms_video',
 'structuresend']
Installed Middleware:
['cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/select_option.html, error at line 1
   __str__ returned non-string (type __proxy__)
   1 : <option value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}> {{ widget.label }} </option>
   2 : 

Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  188.             return template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  173.                 return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  993.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_value_in_context
  972.             value = str(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  397.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __str__
  33.         return self.as_widget()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  93.             renderer=self.form.renderer,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  230.         return self._render(self.template_name, context, renderer)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in _render
  235.         return mark_safe(renderer.render(template_name, context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/renderers.py" in render
  31.         return template.render(context, request=request).strip()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  188.             return template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  173.                 return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  993.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_value_in_context
  972.             value = str(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/cms/page/5/advanced-settings/
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type __proxy__)
```

The problem seems to be a `value = str(value)` not returning a string, although value is said to be 'Inherit the template of the nearest ancestor'. I'm not sure what's happening here.

Apparently it returns a `__proxy__` type, which according to other questions is a type used for translation. What can I do to fix this? I need access to the settings of my page to change the html template it uses.

Comment: What version of CMS and what plugins do you have in the page?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem-- setting `I18N=True` in my settings.py did the trick.

If that doesn't work, try pip installing `django-parler` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who have the same problem.
The settings I18N mustn't set to False. 
If your goal is to deactivate multi language site you can delete "i18n_patterns" in urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/issues/6908#issuecomment-733911252) on the github

modify the `urls.py` as follows

```
# replace 
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(path("admin/", admin.site.urls), path("", include("cms.urls")))

# with 
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
        path("admin/", admin.site.urls), 
        path("", include("cms.urls")),
        prefix_default_language=False # NOTICE THIS HERE
        )
```

and in `settings.py` keep `USE_I18N = True`.